# phpmyadmin login as root

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a cpanel install on my server and phpmyadmin setup on it. At the commandline I have imported a database from another server that I want to use. When I open phpmyadmin I don't see the imported DB. I'm guessing that it is because the user that phpmyadmin has setup doesn't have permissions to use that DB. How can I force phpmyadmin to login as root so that I can see all my DB's?

I tried adding the following to my config.inc.php:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'root';      
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = '';
```

but phpmyadmin still shows me logged in as:

```
User: cpses_blbfomiPKo@localhost
```

Comment: The question should not be _"How to login as root?"_, but **How to import a db into cpanel?**

Comment: Just trying to force it to login as root instead of the cpanel users it creates

Comment: Try [displaying privileges for current user](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html), maybe it's not a matter of privileges but something is wrong elsewhere (no db created, no db selected on import and so on..)

Comment: It is a privileges issue, I changed the privileges for the cpanel user and I could see the DB, the problem is that cpanel keeps creating new users every time I login. Thats why I want to force it to use a fixed user.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out!

The key was to set the auth_type to **config** as show below, my default was cpanel. It them was able to use the username and password I set in the rest of the config.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'admin';      // MySQL user
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'mypass';
```